# How do you combine two data frames with quantities of items in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, merge

I am working in `R` using data frame containing quantities of items (which are non-negative integers).  Here is an example of two data frames called `BASKET1` and `BASKET2`.  In both cases, an item appears in the data frame only if it has a quantity of at least one.  Items appear in each data frame in alphabetical order.

```
BASKET1
    Vegetable  Quantity
1     Carrots         3
2   Cucumbers         2
3    Parsnips         5
4      Celery         1
5      Onions        12

BASKET2
    Vegetable  Quantity
1     Carrots        10
2      Onions         6
3     Rhubarb         2
```

I am trying to create a function that combines two baskets of items into a single basket, adding up all of the items in both baskets.  This is a kind of merge operation, except that I actually want to sum the quantities in the baskets.  It is quite simple to obtain the list of items by using the `unique` function:

```
VEGETABLES <- unique(BASKET1$Vegetable, BASKET2$Vegetable);
```

I am having more difficulty finding a simple way to get the vector of quantities corresponding to this vector of items, to build the data frame of the combined baskets.  I think there is a way to do this using some kind of simple lookup query, but all the methods I have tried lead to code that is cumbersome.

---

**Question:** What is the simplest way to find the vector of quantities corresponding to the combined vector of items?

Comment: try `aggregate(Quantity   ~ Vegetable, rbind(BASKET1,BASKET2), sum)`

Comment: Yep, akrun is right. You essentially want to make one big 'long' data file which has multiple entries for each `Vegetable` and `Quantity`. You can then get the sum by group using several methods - `aggregate` being a common one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `rbind` to rbind the two datasets and `aggregate` to get the `sum` of 'Quantity' by 'Vegetable

```
aggregate(Quantity ~ Vegetable, rbind(BASKET1,BASKET2), sum)
```